# Replace text with multiple unique values each time(AutoIt)

Tags: windows, autoit, replace, text-manipulation

Is there any way to replace text that appears several times in a .txt file with a unique value each time? To be more specific:

This is the given document:

> value="something"
>   other text lines
>   value="something"
>   other text lines
>   ...

This is a text file from which I want to take the values:

> car
>   cat
>   ...

What I want is to automatically replace "something" with a different value each time taken from the other text file, so the given document will turn into this:

> value="car"
>   other text lines
>   value="cat"
>   other text lines
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in AutoIT.

I would read in the second file (car,cat...) using _FileReadToArray(). Then use the function _ReplaceStringInFile().

The below code should get you started in the right direction. FYI: this is not the most efficient code since it opens the file several times.

```
    $replacementStrings = _FileReadToArray($fileName2)
    $ctr = 0
    While ($ctr < UBound($replacementStrings))
      _ReplaceStringInFile($fileName1,"something",$replacementStrings[$ctr],0,0) 
      ;last 0 says only to replaced the first occurrence.
      $ctr+=1
    Wend
```

FYI: if "something" appears in other spots in the main file, you will need to write this differently.